# Good printer for fine art photos which works well under Linux?

Tags: linux, printer

I'm looking for a printer to print fine art photos in color and in B&W from a Linux machine.  These prints will be mounted and displayed.  They don't have to be museum quality or anything, but should be better than typical office color printer output.

I need to print at several sizes, up to about 22" or so.

I'm in the US and hoping to keep it under $400 (USD).  It's important that it works well under Linux since I have no other OS.

Comment: 300 dpi (objective measure of printing quality) is about the standard for printers. And just to be sure, could you specify what [ISO A Size 22" is?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#/media/File:A_size_illustration2_with_letter_and_legal.svg) (e.g. A4, A5, etc.) ?

Comment: I believe the closest match is A2.

Comment: Would you be comfortable settling for A3? Most "Large Format Printers" support up to this paper size, and the jump in cost to accommodate for an A2 paper size will make it very difficult to keep under your budget. People selling A2 printers are pretty much only accommodating for "museum quality" prints.

Comment: Thinking about it, A3 should be OK - I could use an online service to print the few larger photos.